# Simulate background-image with attachment: fixed using <picture>

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive header with a `<picture>` element, that would behave like a background image with a fixed attachment. The reason I'm doing this is so that I can specify different images on different pages. This is the abbreviated HTML.

```
<header>
    <picture>
        <source srcset="sm.jpg">
        <source srcset="md.jpg">
        <source srcset="lg.jpg">
        <img src="/assets/images/md-fraye.jpg">
    </picture>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
</header>
```

What CSS should I use for the image to remain contained within the header, but stay fixed as the page scrolls up, eventually disappearing as the header is gone? I've tried using position: fixed and z-index:-1, but then the `<picture>` overflows the `<header>` and there's nothing I seem to be able to do about it.

I'm trying to do this with the  element because I want the image to be responsive but I'd rather not use JS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up doing it:

```
.cover, .content, {
  max-width: 16rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem 1rem 1.5rem;}

.content {
  background-color: white;}

.cover img {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 20rem;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 10rem); 
  @media only screen and (max-width: 20rem) {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<header class="cover">
  <picture>
    <source="image-sm.jpg">
    <img src="image.jpg">
  </picture>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
<main class="content">
some content
</main>
```

It seems to work. I'm not sure how compatible it is, though.